# Why do my calculation doesn't work in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to make calculations using only state(without reducers, even if it looks strange). I have to calculate totalVat and I've already tried this:

```
 const calcTotalVat = () => {
const totalVat = parseFloat(subtotalValue * totalVatValue) / 100;
return parseFloat(totalVat);};
```

But it doesn't work. Or correctly to say it works partly. It shows the expected result in console, but doesn't display in UI. The problem is, as I think, that input converts number to string and result is NaN.(screen lower)

[image]

The output of TotalVat should be 360 and 240 is previous result as you can see in the console. Because, 3600 * 10 / 100 = 360. As you can see everything depends on that number which you can choose in input. For example, if you write 50, It'll show the result of 1800(3600 * 50 / 100).  Can someone see what's the problem?

To 'listen' the input I've created state:

```
const [totalVatValue, setTotalVatValue] = useState(0);
```

And this function to keep tracking every keystroke:

```
const listenTotalVat = (event) => {
    setTotalVatValue(event.target.value);
  };
```

Connected everything here:

```
<div className={classes["total-vat"]}>
                  <span>Total Vat:</span>
                  <div className={classes["total-sum"]}>
                    <span className={classes["input-wrapper"]}>
                      <input
                        value={totalVatValue}
                        onChange={listenTotalVat}
                      ></input>
                      <span>%</span>
                    </span>
                    <span className={classes.sum}>${totalVatValue}</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

And also trying to execute my calcTotalVat function when my calculations update:

```
const updateItemHandler = (index, inputName, value) => {
    listItems[index] = { ...listItems[index], [inputName]: value };
    calculateTotal();
    calcTotalVat();
  };
```

Here is my previous function where I calculated Total:

```
const calculateTotal = () => {
    let subtotal = 0;

    listItems.map((item) => {
      const itemTotal = parseFloat(item.unit_costs) * parseFloat(item.unit);
      return (subtotal = subtotal + itemTotal);
    });

    setSubtotal(subtotal);
  };
```

And it's used here:

```
<p className={classes["sub-total"]}>
                  <span>Sub Total: </span>
                  <span>${subtotalValue}</span>
                </p>
```

And called in updateItemHandler.

In the end I want to make function to calculate Grand Total(Sub-Total + Total Vat). Help me with creating it, please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're returning undefined. Instead of `return console.log(parseFloat(totalVat));`, use `console.log(totalVat); return totalVat;`

Comment: @anut no effect on that. Already tried.

Comment: Try posting a minimal reproducible example. The code you have given won't work directly, so it's hard to tell where the issue is.

Comment: @anut I can add GitHub repo or  CodeSandbox. And everything you need is in that file I've posted under the screenshot

Comment: A CodeSandbox link works, but it's best to keep your posts short and remove any unrelated code.

Comment: @anut I've shortened everything. Now there is everything related to this specific issue

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't return `return console.log(parseFloat(totalVat));};`, but
`return parseFloat(totalVat)};`. Why you try to return console.log? It is function that just prints the value in browser console.

Comment: I've tried that. No effect. Still doesn't work

Comment: Yes, I forgot to delete that console.log, but it still doesn't work.